# How to test if a type exists in a concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

How can I test if a member type exists in a concept template argument, i.e. for `typename Container`, test for `Container::reverse_iterator` ? What's the proper requires-clause ?

Answer (score 14):

We do this with the aptly named [type requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Type_requirements):

```
template<class Container>
concept has_reverse_iterator = requires {
    typename Container::reverse_iterator;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the type to exist, follow answer of @StoryTeller above.

If you want the type to exist and fulfill a specific concept, then do the:

```
template<class Container>
concept has_reverse_iterator
   = std::random_access_iterator<typename Container::reverse_iterator>;
```